# how can I upgrade my project of laravel 5.0 directly to 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

There is an old project made in laravel 5.0.35 framework by some other developer, now my job is to add some new features to that project but I am familiar with laravel 5.4 so what I think would be good aproach is that I upgrade this project in 5.4 then do my work. But I don't know how to do it.
P.S. I have seen laravel upgrade docs in which they upgrade version by version. Is it possible to upgrade this project directly to laravel 5.4 skipping that version by version upgradation?

Comment: I you are familiar with laravel 5.4, than you can easily work with 5.3 also, their is no need to update just for this reason

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade

Comment: @MayankPandeyz that project is in laravel 5.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

in your laravel directory type

```
composer update
```

and it will be update your laravel project

there is a composer.json file in root and you can find version of your laravel

```
"laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
```

it shows dependencies that you want to upgrade

dont forget to get backup before upgrade

Comment: This seems to be an extreme simplification, surely op must expect quite a bit of work in addition to run a composer command

Comment: Command ran successfully, but composer.json file is still showing "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",

Comment: And what about the file structure? Do I need to change it manually?

Comment: Thanks mate. Now this error is coming.
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider' not found

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can update it but folder structure is changed in laravel 5.4. so you can face problem in it.
Go in composer.json and change the laravel version then
 update composer  with command .